# Fetch from a GraphQL API with keycloak authentication

Tags: graphql, keycloak

I'm making the bot of an app that is made with a GraphQL API, but require keycloak authentication. The creator of the API sent me these environments variables

> NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_REALM="something"
> NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_HOST="http://url"
> NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID="something-else"

Already made the connection with the API, but give me the error:

> "Your token key is expired or invalid."

This is the code to connect to the API:

```
fetch("https://url/graphql",{
    method:'POST',
    headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `
      {
        services{
          name
        }
      }
      `
    
    }),
       })  
 .then(res => res.json())   
.then(data => {console.log(data)} )
```

Where should i put the authentication info of keycloak or i'm doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The API is protected with keycloak, so you need to pass some authentication info on requests

Normally this is done via the `Authorization` Header where you pass a `Bearer` Token. This header need to be added to every API Request.

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhd....fdfd
```

But first you need to authenticate to keycloak to issue a Bearer-Token for your client.

Take a look at Client adapters provided by keycloak. This client adapters handle the authentication workflow for your app. Maybe the `JavaScript` or `Node.js` adapter is the right thing for you
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_javascript_adapter

The adapters can be initialized with the Realm-Informations (url, realm, client_id) provided by the api creator.

Comment: I'm using nestjs and i'm a little stuck, could you put a example? I'd be very grateful

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no experience in `nestjs`, but imho the example usage of the nodejs adapter https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_nodejs_adapter is pretty good documented. maybe you can get additional input from this guide https://medium.com/devops-dudes/securing-node-js-express-rest-apis-with-keycloak-a4946083be51#e890

Comment: I will check it out but if it is not to much to ask how you'd do it in node, I mean to get the token, because the documentation don't say anything about it